# MFC dynamic adding controls with scroll bar

Tags: mfc

I want to add controls, including buttons, edit box and custom controls, dynamically in a MFC MDI application. I am using from view and I want to create the following GUI.
[image]
What I want to do is:

- I am able to create those row of controls(Button, Edit box and custom
  control) dynamically.
- I can have many rows of those controls.
- When there are too many rows and the form view has no space to
  display them, a scroll bar will appear.

I had read some resources talking about how to create controls dynamically. But I am still wondering how to insert them into `something` so that I can have a scroll bar when there are too many rows of controls I have to handle.

Comment: I think the article on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262954 is good base for you to begin

Comment: @sergiol thank you, but what I have to do is a dialog split into two parts while each part has its own scroll bar

Comment: I think you can do that using splitters.

Comment: @sergiol, thank you, I am also reading related tech

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xttbe5t.aspx for splitter reference.